# How to stop a turtle netlogo

Tags: button, netlogo, forever

I want to know how to stop my turtle (patron) from moving forward if there is a black patch ahead of it. The problem with this is that the go button is a forever button. I have tried to make the turtle turn using coordinates but of course that will not stop the turtles from moving forward since its a forever button. This is in `NetLogo`, just to clarify.

```
to go  ;; customer procedure
  ask patrons [
    fd 1
    while [any? other patrons-here]
      [ fd 1 ]
    if pxcor = -15 and pycor = 14
      [rt 90]
      if pxcor = -14 and pycor = 14

  ]

  tick   
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely clear whether you have multiple patrons. If the problem is that you want to stop the model running, then you can use the `stop` primitive. If the problem is that you want to stop a particular patron so it can do something else, then you could use the `ifelse` primitive to check if it moves or does the other thing each tick

```
globals [numwant]
turtles-own [new?]

to setup
  clear-all
  set numwant 5
  create-turtles 1 [set color green
                    set new? TRUE]
  ask n-of 30 patches [set pcolor red]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
   ask turtles with [new?]
   [ ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 != red
     [ fd 1]
     [ set color yellow
       set new? FALSE
       ifelse count turtles < numwant
       [spawn]
       [stop]
     ]
   ]
  tick
end

to spawn
  hatch 1 [set color green
           setxy random-xcor random-ycor
           set heading random-float 360
           set new? TRUE]
end
```

Edited to add the multiple turtles and sequential spawn in response to comment. However, you might want to think through your logic a bit, it is unusual to want only one turtle moving at a time.

Comment: Thank you so much I have been trying to figure out how to use stop and this was perfect. However I have neglected to ask if I am creating more than one patron and in my setup, I am creating the amount of patrons in a slider say 15, how do I make one turtle spawn in first, get to a certain patch lets say that is green color, then ask for the second patron to spawn in and so on? @JenB

Comment: @Ivan I think JenB has already answered your original question. You should accept her answer (with the big checkmark next to it) and open a new question, to ask something new.